# Call and assign specific variables in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell, multiple-columns

My dataset has this format, 3 columns and some unique variables

```
A = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
B = [B1, B2, B3]
C = [C1, C2, C3, C4, C5]
```

I want to call a specific variable, and then assign a value to it.

Example 1:

```
A     B     C
A2    B3    C5
A1    B2    C2
A3    B1    C4
A4    B2    C3
A2    B3    C1
```

Call all [A1, B2, C3] and assign them to be equal to [1, 2,3]

```
A     B     C
A2    B3    C5
1     2     C2
A3    B1    C4
A4    2     3
A2    B3    C1
```

@Scott Boston suggested using dictionary to assign the value in this way

Example 2: I want to assign the value one by one in a loop, such as A1 first, then do some calculation, then assign A2, and so on. Then how can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can actually assgin one variable one time with `replace`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, use `replace` with dictionary:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A2  B3  C5
1  A1  B2  C2
2  A3  B1  C4
3  A4  B2  C3
4  A2  B3  C1
```

Create a dictionary for replacement.

```
d = {'A1':1,'B2':2,'C3':3}
```

@Wen suggest using this statement to create dictionary:

```
d=dict(zip( ['A1', 'B2', 'C3'],[1,2,3] ))

df_out = df.replace(d)

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A2  B3  C5
1   1   2  C2
2  A3  B1  C4
3  A4   2   3
4  A2  B3  C1
```

Comment: Maybe using d=dict(zip( ['A1', 'B2', 'C3'],[1,2,3] )), to create the dict

Comment: Thank you! If I want to assign the value to the variable one by one in a loop, how can I do that? Such as, change the value of A1, do some calculation, then change the value of A2, and so on.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen check my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As for your 2nd example, where you want to assign values iteratively, you an do it this way.

```
var = ['A1','B2','C3']
val = [1,2,3]

for i in range(len(val)):
    df = df.replace({var[i]:val[i]})
    # your calculations here...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your answer I believe `apply()` function of pandas will be a more efficient solution.
Eg:

```
def my_func(a):
    #your computation here

df['A'].apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

Comment: IMHO, `apply` does not fit in the context of the second problem.

Comment: apply() function is used to assign function to all the elements of DF iteratively which is what the questioner is asking for in the second part of the question.

Comment: She does not want to assign to all the elements. Can you read it again? Just `A1` for example, needs to be replaced. `A1` is not a column name. I think you mistaken that.

Comment: Please read the second comment of the first solution where the questioner asked the second question.

Comment: I think Mukarram Pasha's answer more fit in the context. But if you can edit your answer for a bit, I will remove my downvote.